# How to place vertical lines in the margin

Tags: margins, marginpar, layout

I want to put a timeline in the margin so the reader can quickly get a sense of the theme of every paragraph. I am accomplishing this with the `marpar` command. However, I also want to put a vertical line between each `marpar` box so the reader understands that there is a passage of time. See the screenshot below. Note, I added teh red lines myself using Microsoft Powerpoint simply for the purposes of illustrating what it is I want to achieve.

[image]

Here is the MWE code

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{report} % Article class of KOMA-script with 11pt font and a4 format
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example

\begin{document}

    \marginpar{1974 \par Time travel invented}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    
    \marginpar{1984 \par Decepticons invade Earth}
    \lipsum[1-1]

    \marginpar{1994 \par Parallel dimensions invade}
    \lipsum[1-1]

    \marginpar{2004 \par Sun explodes}
    \lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

To compile, I just issue the command `pdflatex mwe.tex`

Obviously if a package exists to achieve exactly what I want, that would be great. However, I am willing to settle for an easy solution whereby I eyeball the line left/right and manually set its length myself. As an example, it could be a tikz line that gets pushed into the margin

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch, I hope the question meets the community guidelines

Comment: If you are willing to do it by "brute force", there are ways to absolutely position things on a page. Analogy is HTML "position:absolute" with X and Y position. Have a look at the `eso-pic` package `AtPageUpperLeft`. There are also other packages that involve page positioning. Another possibility is to use `\smash{something}` along with box commands, to place something relative to where the command is written.

Comment: And of course there is the `textpos` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the contents of the `\marginpar` inside a `tikzmarknode`. Then (before the end of the page) create a `tikzpicture` with options `overlay, remember picture`. You can then use ordinary Ti*k*Z commands to draw the timeline.

For convenience, I placed the styles in a `tikzset` for easy editing.

A few notes:

- Since the `\marginpar` contents are now a node label, you can use `align=left` in the style, and `\\` for a line break.
- The `\draw` command makes use of the built-in `current page` node. You can adjust the distance to the page edge, or use `\draw[timeline] (A|-current page.north)--(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(D|-current page.south);` to draw the line right to the edge of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{report} % Article class of KOMA-script with 11pt font and a4 format
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{
    margin/.style={align=left, text width=2.5cm, inner sep=1mm},
    timeline/.style={red, line width=1.5mm},
    timeball/.style={draw=black, thin, circle, fill=red, minimum size=4mm}
}

\begin{document}

    \marginpar{\tikzmarknode[margin]{A}{1974\\ Time travel invented}}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    
    \marginpar{\tikzmarknode[margin]{B}{1984\\ Decepticons invade Earth}}
    \lipsum[1-1]

    \marginpar{\tikzmarknode[margin]{C}{1994\\ Parallel dimensions invade}}
    \lipsum[1-1]

    \marginpar{\tikzmarknode[margin]{D}{2004\\ Sun explodes}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[timeline] ([yshift=-4cm]A|-current page.north)node[timeball]{}--(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--([yshift=4cm]D|-current page.south)node[timeball]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a very reliable solution, and it is very easy to copy/paste as the number of points increases. Thanks

Comment: @Sandy G Excellent work (+1), like always. How I can continue the timeline after the first page? Thanks.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro: Not sure if this is what you mean, but you could do `\draw[timeline] ([yshift=-4cm]A|-current page.north)node[timeball]{}--(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(D|-current page.south)`. Then on the next page, a new set of tikzmarknodes and a new tikzpicture with `(A|-current page.north)--(E)`, etc.